# Spring scheduled tasks: from XML to annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-annotations

In our Spring web-application, we are moving from XML based configuration to  Annotation based configuration.

I'm stuck with a scheduled task defined with this XML

```
<task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="cacheScheduler">
    <task:scheduled ref="currencyExchangeRateTask" method="cacheCurrencyExchangeRates" cron="0 0 8,20 * * *" />
</task:scheduled-tasks>
```

There are multiple schedulers in our web-application. And this task needs to be executed on the scheduler with id `cacheScheduler`.

I have now the following annotation in place

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 8,20 * * *")
public void cacheCurrencyExchangeRates() {
    ...
}
```

This is executing on the default scheduler.

How can this be fixed without XML configuration?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do it through [`@Scheduled`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html) directly. It doesn't provide any annotation members to specify a bean reference name.

Instead, you have to use [`SchedulingConfigurer`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/SchedulingConfigurer.html). Define a `@Configuration` class. Annotate it with `@EnableScheduling` and `@ComponentScan` for the packages with component types that have `@Scheduled` annotated methods. Then have the class implement `SchedulingConfigurer`.

The [`ScheduledTaskRegistrar`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/config/ScheduledTaskRegistrar.html) provided through its [`configureTasks`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/SchedulingConfigurer.html#configureTasks-org.springframework.scheduling.config.ScheduledTaskRegistrar-) method lets you set a task scheduler.

For example:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.example.tasks")
@EnableScheduling
class Tasks implements SchedulingConfigurer {
    @Bean
    public TaskScheduler cacheScheduler() {
        return new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar) {
        taskRegistrar.setTaskScheduler(cacheScheduler());
    }
}
```

All the `@Scheduled` methods discovered through this `@Configuration` class will now be using the `TaskScheduler` defined within.

If you need different `@Scheduled` methods to use different `TaskScheduler` instances, you'll need different `@Configuration` classes, similarly to needing different `<task:scheduled-tasks .../>` elements.